# PHP: if Admin logged in then editable content should be enabled so he can edit

Tags: php, html, css, admin

I want to make like a Web-shop where the admin can change everything.
When he logs in every div should be editable. This is an example of a product he should be able to edit on the page itself.

```
<div class="caption">

    <h4 class="pull-right">€74.99</h4>
    <h4><a href="#">Third Product</a>
    </h4><p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur    
    adipiscing elit.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Is there going to be an edit button?

Comment: And what is the question for us? What ever it is, it's most likely going to be too broad, please do have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works.

Comment: Items should be dynamic (or database driven) to achieve 'edits'.

Comment: It would be better if there's an edit button @PremRaj

Comment: I could insert the information into the database would that be a good idea?
@Epodax

Comment: With the information you've given, this is the best answer I can give. `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could use input text boxes and make them readonly if you are not an admin.
    
If not you could echo out a completely different div with textboxes for the admin and echo out what you have now for normal people.

```
<?php if(admin){ ?>
<div class="caption">
    <input type="text" name="price" value="€74.99><br>
    <input type="text" name="product" value="Third Product"><br>
    <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="5">This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</textarea>                   
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="caption">
    <h4 class="pull-right">€74.99</h4>
    <h4><a href="#">Third Product</a></h4>
    <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur    
    adipiscing elit.</p>        
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

what you would do is have a database and a table in that database named what ever and you would put Id int varchar (255) primary auto_increment like price, name and description then you would have a backend with inputs containing that like for example:

```
         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'rootpassword';
            $dbname = '';

            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];

            $sql = "UPDATE whatever ". "SET price = $price ". 
               "WHERE id= $id" ;
            $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysqli_close($conn);
         }else {
            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "filename.php">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">
                  <?php $query = "SELECT * from whatever";?

$res = mysqli_query($query, $conn);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res) {
$price = $res['price'];
//etc fields
}
?>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">price</td>
                        <td><input name = "price" type = "text" 
                           id = "price" value="<?php echo price; ?>"></td>
                     </tr>etc fields

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
            <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

that is a quick example on how to do that in the backend i have not include all fields you can take my example and continue adding the rest of the fields